# Extract a list of tarfile using python

Tags: python, zip, tar

I have a folder (**dataset_folder**) that contains 10 *.tar files.
Here is my code to extract them in a specific path.

```
listtar=glob.glob(dataset_folder+'/*.tar')
for file in listtar:
    tar=tarfile.open(file)
    tar.extractall(path=dataset_folder)
    tar.close()
```

Note that **dataset_folder** is under the current directory.
 **I get an error**

```
ReadError: unexpected end of data
```

*Note also that I can untar files manually without problems.*

Comment: " I can zip files manually without problems" you mean "untar manually" right ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes. It is corrected. Thanks

Comment: are you getting an error for the first file or for _some_ file?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I tried the code manually (listtar[index] instead of x ) and for several index I get the same error.

Comment: are you sure your .tar files are .tar files? some programs could recognize supported archives only by the magic number. Check the start of your files with an hex editor.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, some files are corrupted as mentioned in the answer. So, your second comment is correct. I toke randomly some index and I got an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to handle corrupt files directly from Python, catch the relevant exception and skip the corrupt file:

```
listtar=glob.glob(dataset_folder+'/*.tar')
for file in listtar:
    try:
        with tarfile.open(file) as tar:
            tar.extractall(path=dataset_folder)
    except tarfile.ReadError:
        print("File {} is corrupt".format(file))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like one of the tar files is corrupt or of a format that tarfile can't handle

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.ReadError

If you've got access to tar in a shell then try something like this, replacing "tmp" with your dataset folder.

```
for i in tmp/*.tar; do tar -C tmp -xvf $i || echo "$i is a problem"; done
```